# Salesforce Open CTI reqAdapterUrl: Visualforce page or hosted in third party?

Tags: opencti

I am working on designing a contact center interface in Salesforce using Open CTI to integrate between two system. I will be using Lightning Experience in Service cloud for the softphone.

As I am going through the Open CTI developer guide, I see that `reqAdapterUrl` can either be a link where the app is hosted, or it can be a visualforce page in salesforce.

What are the pros and cons of having the app hosted somewhere vs having a visualforce page? Is there a best practices for the implementation?

From my reading, here are few pros and cons that I have come up with:

**Hosting the page somewhere**

PROS

- There is no need to have an app in AppExchange (so no Salesforce certification process?)
- End users can download the call center definition file (from some other interface), and upload it to their salesforce instance. And configure their salesforce to use the softphone
- When pushing updates, I can update the app where I have it hosted

CONS

- the app needs to have absolute path to Open CTI javascript library, and the path will include `MyDomainName`, which will be different for each salesforce instance (or each customer)
- There is some added complexity to use Salesforce Lighting Design System

**Visualforce page**

PROS

- Adding reference to Open CTI library, and Salesforce Lighting Design System is easy
- Each salesforce instance (or each customer) will have the visualforce page, and static resources for the app in their instance

CONS

- Need to create app for AppExchange
- Not sure how I would push out releases to existing customer who are using the app in production.

**NOTE: My list of pros and cons could be completely wrong as I am still reading and learning Salesforce Open CTI**

I have looked at the user guide for Amazon Connect, and Twilio Flex. Amazon Connect has an app in AppExchange, and it looks like their softphone is a visualforce page. On the other hand, Twilio has the app hosted somewhere.

What would be the best approach?